# Using Dosbox to use wps program that only uses lpt1, need to use usb printer

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer

ok so I have a friend that is using an old wps program using dosbox.. the options on the program only allow print to serial or parallel but I guess that doesn't matter since I read dosbox doesn't support printing.. I read this could be achieved by using mega dos box but the next obstacle is he has only a usb printer.. is there a way he can bypass to use his usb printer or will he have to print to file? Iam all new to this so please be Detailed thanks.. btw he is using win 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should do the trick.

- Edit the DosBox configuration file. 
  Under the [printer] heading add the following:

  > printoutput=printer

  Under the [parallel] heading add:

  > parallel1=enabled dev:lpt1
- Share the printer (even if nobody else is going to use it). Go to printer properties, click the Sharing tab and share it. Make a note of the sharename of the printer.
- Redirect output to the USB printer. Start a DOS (not DosBox) prompt and type:

  > net use lpt1:  \computer_name\printer_sharename  /persistent:yes

More info can be found [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/268815-45-print-dosbox-local-printer)